# Very slow boot with Ubuntu 16.04 on XPS 13 with SSD

Tags: boot, dmesg

I am experiencing very slow booting with fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell XPS 13 9333. I have run dmesg and saved the output here: http://pastebin.com/6vGwv5gc.

After I managed to reduce boot time to 10s again (see answer below) I deleted some misleading analysis from the OP.

Here is the output:

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 30.712s
  └─multi-user.target @1min 30.712s
   └─getty.target @1min 30.712s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 30.712s
     └─rc-local.service @1min 30.456s +20ms
      └─network.target @1min 30.456s
       └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 31.916s +102ms
        └─basic.target @1min 30.138s
         └─sockets.target @1min 30.138s
          └─snapd.socket @1min 30.137s +372us
           └─sysinit.target @1min 30.134s
            └─systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service @1.464s
             └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @860ms
              └─system.slice @96ms
               └─-.slice @94ms
```

Most appreciated if someone could give me some hints here.

Comment: As far as I can see using the disks utility my swap is not mounted. Therefore I did the following:


1. sudo mkswap /dev/sda5 # That'll remake swap and give it a new UUID,
 2. Edit /etc/fstab #In the line for swap delete the old UUID and replace it with the NEW UUID you got from step #1
  3. reboot # after reboot you should now see that your SWAP is being mounted correctly

which was suggested here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2310935

Still my swap (which is sda5) is not mounted during boot.

Comment: I'm on my phone so not sure but you might have to run 'sudo update-grub' after changing fstab.

Comment: Ok. In my /etc/fstab the line with swap was uncommented. I removed the '#' and now the swap is beeing mounted. Nevertheless the boottime has not improved, not even an bit.

Comment: How long between power on and log on prompt?

Comment: as you can see from the dmsg lines i posted in OP the time till log on screen takes about 158 seconds. While before (with 14.04) it was about 20 to 35 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I managed to reduce booting time to 10s again.

How did I do this?

It seems swap partition was not configured correct during install. I did a fresh install of 16.04 but told it to use the old swap partition which was located at sda5. As mentioned above in my /etc/fstab the line with swap was uncommented. I removed the '#' and the swap was beeing mounted. Nevertheless the boottime did not improve. When turning swap off an on again by executing `sudo swapoff -a` and then `sudo swapon -a` I got an error saying cryptswap is not foung.

I checked with the `free` command if swap is used  while running ram intensive programs. Swap was not used at all.

So I turned swap off with `sudo swapoff -a`.

Recreated swap `sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/sda5`. (sda5 was my swap partition, if yours is another one replace this).

Now I copied the UUID from the terminal output which appeared after executing the command. (if output is: `UUID=e933aaa4-620a-4657-a988-71539a2e36ab` you want to copy `e933aaa4-620a-4657-a988-71539a2e36ab`)

I checked fstab with `cat /etc/fstab`, which gave me:

> `#swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation`
>
> UUID=23b67f5b-52cf-4f95-881c-62c2b962ec06 / none swap sw 0 0
>
> /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

I removed : `UUID=23b67f5b-52cf-4f95-881c-62c2b962ec06 / none swap sw 0 0`

(You can edit fstab with `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.)

So my fstab now looks like this regarding the swap area:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

After that I edited crypttab with `sudo nano /etc/crypttab`' and replaced the UUID with the one I copied in the step above.

Now crypttab looks like:

`cryptswap1 UUID=e933aaa4-620a-4657-a988-71539a2e36ab /dev/urandom swap,offset=1$`

Finaly I executed `sudo swapon -a` an rebooted. You need to reboot for this change to take effect, because only when booting will `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` be created.